# Trying to get property of non-object in Console.log

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have here two different query. First query is for both table that has a same item_code, and second table is only for table 1 that has a item code. I add console.log to run a script on the other page. The process of my code is if the first query (query for both table) failed to execute, the second query (query for table 1 only) execute. Both query executing correctly but I received this error on console.log.

"
**Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in **C:\xampplite\htdocs\edit.php** on line **21,23,25**
0"

The line 21,23 and 25 error is my if else statement. I need to get console.log `1`.

Why is that?

Any help will appreciated.

Both table have the item code `A000321`

```
table 1     |   table 2
            |
item_code   |  item_code
------------|--------------
   A000321  |    A000321
```

Only table 1 have the item code `A000321`

```
table 1     |   table 2
            |
item_code   |  item_code
------------|--------------
   A000321  |
```

Update.php

```
<?php
$val1_id= $_POST['val1_id'];
$val1_item_copy= $_POST['val1_item_copy'];
$val1_catcode= $_POST['val1_catcode'];
$val1_itemcode= $_POST['val1_itemcode'];

$sql = $mysqli->query("
UPDATE  code t1
INNER JOIN
        app t2
ON      t2.item_code= t1.item_code
SET     t1.item = '$val1_item_copy',t2.item_name = '$val1_item_copy'
WHERE   t1.item_code = '$val1_itemcode' AND t1.cat_code = '$val1_catcode';
")or die('There was an error running the query [' . $mysqli->error . ']');

if(($sql->num_rows)>= 1){
echo '1';
} else if(($sql->num_rows) == 0) {
$sql1 = $mysqli->query("UPDATE code SET item='$val1_item_copy' WHERE id='$val1_id'")or die('There was an error running the query [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
if(($sql1->num_rows)>= 1){
echo '1';
} else {
echo '0';
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Why don't you check for errors? mysqli_error() would tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Where are `$val1_item_copy` and `$val1_id` being defined? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- just like this? $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "database") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)) to mysqli_query();

Comment: `$sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE code SET item='$val1_item_copy' WHERE id='$val1_id'") or die('There was an error running the query [' . $mysqli->error . ']');`

Comment: @Fred-ii- where I can see the errors? It doesn't appear in my page or in console.

Comment: Errors should appear on screen. I guess something weird's going on or there are no errors. Sometimes, SQL sees your code as being correct but can't quite find differentiate on how it's supposed to handle/output the data.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yah I think there's no error in my query. Because I already used it before for some test. And why success = 1 appears on my console? Help me please

Comment: I think it's because you have two `if($sql){` since your query isn't failing, it's echoing out two `1`. Least, that's what I make of it. Try renaming the variable for the second query to `$sql2 = $mysqli->query("UPDATE code SET item='$val1_item_copy' WHERE id='$val1_id'");
if($sql2){`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I already done doing that, but it has a same result. :(

Comment: @Fred-ii- If there's another to do this process?

Comment: if the first query runs correctly and received console.log 1, then the 2nd will not get chance to excecute since it is in the else cond?

Comment: I run the both query just by adding if(($sql->num_rows)>= 1){. But the problem there's no console.log.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I executed the both query. But the problem is there's no console.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just edit some details. I used  `if($mysqli->affected_rows >= 1)` instead of `if(($sql->num_rows)>= 1)`

```
if($mysqli->affected_rows >= 1) {
echo '1';
} else {
$sql1 = $mysqli->query("UPDATE code SET item='$val1_item_copy' WHERE id='$val1_id'")or die('There was an error running the query [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
if($mysqli->affected_rows >= 1) {
echo '1';
} else {
echo '0';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're likely getting a "1" because the update query is successful. This does not mean it made any changes, just that it didn't crash.

You can check the affected records by checking

```
printf("Affected rows (Non-Select): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);
```